# Enabling/Disabling Select Boxes based on options chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to enable/disable 2 select boxes based on selections made on a third box (controller) using jQuery.
What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user selects any of the first 2 options on the controller Selection box 2 will enable, when the user selects any of the last 2 options it will disable selection box 2 and enable selection box 3. If the user goes back on their selection this should enable once again selection box 2 and disable selection box 3, however it doesn't.

My code runs perfectly on the first iteration, but if the user comes back both boxes remain disabled no matter what his choice is.

Here's the snippet

```js
$(function() {    //document ready

    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
        if ($('#mySelect :selected').data('type') <= 2 ) {  // if user selects the first 2 items
            if ( $('#mySelect2 :selected').text() == "Disabled") {  //if selection 2 text is Disabled 
                     $('#mySelect2 :selected').text('Select Option');  // replace text with Select Option
                     $('#mySelect2').removeAttr('disabled');  //remove disabled attribute from select box
            };
            $('#mySelect').change(function() {
                if ( $('#mySelect :selected').data('type') > 2) {
                        $('#mySelect2').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                        $('#mySelect2').attr('disabled', true);
                 };
            });
             //$('#mySelect').change(function() {    // 
             //        $('#mySelect3').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
             //        $('#mySelect3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             //     });
            }
        else if ($('#mySelect :selected').data('type') > 2 ) {
            if ( $('#mySelect3 :selected').text() == "Disabled") {  // if text on select 3 is "Disabled"
                $('#mySelect3 :selected').text('Select Option'); // changes value for text on first option of 3rd box
                $('#mySelect3').removeAttr('disabled'); // removes disabled on 3rd checkbox
                  };
                    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
                    if ( $('#mySelect :selected').data('type') <= 2) {
                        $('#mySelect3').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                        $('#mySelect3').attr('disabled', true);
                    };
                });
                      //    $('#mySelect').change(function() { 
          //  $('#mySelect2').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        //    $('#myselect3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        };
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

div.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  display:flex;
}

div.result {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.result > p {
  color: red;
}

select {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin:  20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #074481
  }
select option {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
    <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Please Select Option</option>
    <option value="1" data-type="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-type="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-type="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-type="4">option 4</option>
  </select>
  <select name="mySelect2" id="mySelect2" disabled>
    <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Disabled</option>
    <option value="1" data-type="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-type="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-type="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-type="4">option 4</option>
  </select>
      <select name="mySelect3" id="mySelect3" disabled>
    <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Disabled</option>
    <option value="1" data-type="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2" data-type="2">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rodcunha/cu07yfzv/12/

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm sure it is probably something really basic but I'm only starting out JS/jQ development and can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

The first is: you cannot attach an event handler each time you enter the same function:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
```

Second point is: reduce complexity and make your code more readable. Avoid:

```
else if ($('#mySelect :selected').data('type') > 2 ) {
```

Another point is to avoid to repeat lines of code like in:

```
$('#mySelect3').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
$('#mySelect3').prop('disabled', true);
$('#mySelect3').text('Disabled');
```

You can chain:

```
$('#mySelect3').prop({selectedIndex: 0,  disabled: true}).find(':selected').text("Disabled");
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function() {    //document ready

    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
        if ($('#mySelect :selected').data('type') <= 2 ) {  // if user selects the first 2 items
            if ( $('#mySelect2 :selected').text() == "Disabled") {  //if selection 2 text is Disabled
                $('#mySelect2 :selected').text('Select Option');  // replace text with Select Option
                $('#mySelect2').removeAttr('disabled');  //remove disabled attribute from select box
            };
            $('#mySelect3').prop({selectedIndex: 0,  disabled: true}).find(':selected').text("Disabled");
        } else  {
            if ( $('#mySelect3 :selected').text() == "Disabled") {  // if text on select 3 is "Disabled"
                $('#mySelect3 :selected').text('Select Option'); // changes value for text on first option of 3rd box
                $('#mySelect3').removeAttr('disabled'); // removes disabled on 3rd checkbox
            };
            $('#mySelect2').prop({selectedIndex: 0,  disabled: true}).find(':selected').text("Disabled");
        };
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

div.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    display:flex;
}

div.result {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.result > p {
    color: red;
}

select {
    min-width: 100px;
    margin:  20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #074481
}
select option {
    line-height: 30px;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
        <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Please Select Option</option>
        <option value="1" data-type="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-type="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-type="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-type="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="mySelect2" id="mySelect2" disabled>
        <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Disabled</option>
        <option value="1" data-type="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-type="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-type="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-type="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="mySelect3" id="mySelect3" disabled>
        <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Disabled</option>
        <option value="1" data-type="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="2" data-type="2">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It took a little adapting and banging against the wall but in the end it worked. Appreciate your help Gaetano.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {    //document ready

$('#mySelect').change(function() {
    if ($('#mySelect :selected').data('type') <= 2 ) {  // if user selects the first 2 items
        $('#mySelect2').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#mySelect3').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else if($('#mySelect :selected').data('type') > 2 ){
        $('#mySelect3').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#mySelect2').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

    }
    else{
        $('#mySelect2').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#mySelect3').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onChange event for selectors and tie them to their own functions which will make things much easier and cleaner. So it would be something like:

```
<select onchange='myFunction()'>
    <option value="0" data-type="0" disabled selected>Please Select Option</option>
    <option value="1" data-type="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-type="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-type="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-type="4">option 4</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, appreciate your help.